# Only display outline level 1 text and TC field with outline level 2 in TOC

Tags: vba, ms-word, tableofcontents

I'm working with many similar documents given to me, which contains `wdStyleHeading1` and 4-5 `wdStyleHeading2` below each heading 1. Below each `wdStyleHeading1` is a title which I would like to display in the TOC, so it looks like [TOC example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zAO43.png).

I add this title to the TOC as a TC field with `ActiveDocument.TablesOfContents.MarkEntry Range:=Selection.Range, Entry:="TitleSample", Level:=1` for each `wdStyleHEading1` which I encounter in my loop.

I create my TOC with the following code:

```
With ActiveDocument
      .TablesOfContents.Add Range:=Selection.Range, _
            RightAlignPageNumbers:=True, _
            UseHeadingStyles:=True, _
            UpperHeadingLevel:=1, _
            LowerHeadingLevel:=2, _
            UseFields:=True, _
            IncludePageNumbers:=True, _
            AddedStyles:="", _
            UseHyperlinks:=True, _
            HidePageNumbersInWeb:=True, _
            UseOutlineLevels:=True
      .TablesOfContents(1).TabLeader = wdTabLeaderDots
      .TablesOfContents.Format = wdIndexIndent
End With
```

However, I'm at a loss to how I can avoid displaying the 4-5 `wdStyleHeading2` in the TOC, while still displaying the TC field titles I added with the MarkEntry method. I have attempted to use `Paragraph.OutlineDemote` method, but this fails since the document only contains `wdOutlineLevel1` and `wdOutlineLevel2`.

Would the simplest fix be, to just create a style/formatting similar to `wdStyleHeading2` which does not contain an outline level and apply this to all paragraphs which have the `wdStyleHeading2, or is there a way where I can keep the default style and omit it from the TOC?

And a bonus question: Is there a way to omit the `TabLeader` and page numbering for the outline level 1 entries and not outline 1 entries?

Comment: You could try changing LowerHeadingLevel to 1

Comment: Yes you're right, this would fix the problem of displaying excessive wdStyleHeading2, but it also hides the titles that I add with the TC fields command. I will clarify my question, so this is included.

Comment: The TOC field is sufficiently flexible that you can use specific styles to create the outline.  So in your case create an appropriate style that is applied  to your titles.  You'd then create the toc by adding the styles such that wdHeading1 is level 1 and <yourstyle>name is heading 2.  Its also probably easier if you create the toc by setting the text of an empty field.  In this way you can prototype the TOC in Word itself.  Take a look at the \t switch in this rather outdated link https://documentation.help/MS-Office-Word-2003/worefTOCTableOfContents1.htm

Comment: Using a style for you 'title' text also means that you can dispense with the laborious .MarkEntry stuff